# Javascript function not defined and SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="bgTime()">CHANGE BACKGROUND</button>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    </script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function bgTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    if (d getHours() >= 21) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg/H.png')"
    }
    else if (d getHours() >= 18) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg/G.png')"
    }
    else if (d getHours() >= 15) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg/F.png')"
    }
    else if (d getHours() >= 12) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg/E.png')"
    }
    else if (d getHours() >= 9) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg/D.png')"
    }
    else if (d getHours() >= 6) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg/C.png')"
    }
    else if (d getHours() >= 3) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg/B.png')"
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg/A.png')"
    };
};
```

Okay so I am probably just being an idiot somehow, but I cannot find what I am doing wrong. I get two errors:

---

1. "script.js:3 | Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
 2. "(index):3 | onclick | Uncaught ReferenceError: bgTime is not defined "

---

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

P.S. This is just a project for learning JS, don't judge lol.

Comment: Is it really `d getHours()`, not `d.getHours()`?

Comment: I knew I was just being dumb haha thank you!

Comment: The first error occurs, indicating a problem in the loaded JavaScript; with the issue in that code, the function is not "created" and made available for when you click, hence the second error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
d.getHours()
```

`getHours` is a method of `d` which is accessed using the dot `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a period. It should be:
`d.getHours() >= 21` et cetera. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dot notation on all of your `if` statements:

```
if (d.getHours() >= 21) { ... }
```

`bgTime` is not defined because the JS interpreter can't decode your program. Once you fix your `if`s, everything should work fine.

---

**References:**

- [MDN Property Accessors Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)